# Inductive Definition for Lexicographical Order of Strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I've been having a hard time trying to find a conclusive inductive definition for the lexicographical order of strings. Not any specific type like a subset of two strings or anything like that, just a general definition for lexicographic order. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $<_S$ be a well-order on a set $S.$ For $s\in S$  let $pred_{<_S}=\{t\in S: t:t<_S s\}.$ (Pred for predecessors). Let $T=\{S\}\cup \{pred_{<_S}s:s\in S\}.$

Let $<_U$ be a linear order on a set $U.$

The notation $^TU$ is for the set of all functions from $T$ into $U.$ (Sometimes we write $U^T$ instead).

Let $D\subset (^TU).$ Define a relation $<_L$ on $D$ as follows, for all $f,g \in D$ with $f\ne g:$

(i). $\neg (f<_Lf).$

(ii). If $f=\emptyset$ then $f<_Lg.$

(iii). If $\exists x\in dom (f)\cap dom(g)$ such that $f(x)\ne g(x)$ then let $y=\min_{<s}\{x: f(x)\ne g(x)\}.$  Then $f<_Lg$ if $f(y)<_Ug(y)$ and $g<_Lf$ if $ g(y)<f(y).$

(iv). If there does not exist $x\in dom(f)\cap dom(g)$ such that $f(x)\ne g(x),$ observe that since $f\ne g,$ we have either

(A):$\;dom(f)\subsetneq dom(g) \land g|_{dom(f)}=f, $ or

(B): $ \;dom(g)\subsetneq dom(f)\land f|_{dom(g)}=g.$

If (A) then  $f<_Lg.$ If (B) then $g<_Lf$.

Notes: Call $D$ a set of strings. (ii) is a special case of (iv) when $f$ is the empty string.... (iv) is like the dictionary protocol that "and" precedes "android"... (ii) is like the dictionary protocol that "ail" precedes "all".  The "inductive" part of the def'n is implicit in that $<_S$ is a well-order. In general $<_L$ need not be a well-order.

Example. Let $U=[0,1]$ with $ <_U$ being the usual order $<.$ Let $S=\{1,2\}$ with $1<_S 2.$ A member of $U\times U$ can be considered to be a member of $D=\{f\in (^TU): dom(f)=S\}.$ Then for ordered pairs $p=(x,y)$ and $p'=(x',y')$  in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ we have $p<_Lp'\iff [(x<x') \lor (x=x'\land y<y')].$

Comment: This definition is correct, but it doesn't look inductive to me. Specifically, the criterion for when $f<_Lg$ doesn't seem to make any use of the relation $<_L$ on shorter strings.